# Django - custom field, using signals in contribute_to_class

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom field extending TextField. And it takes a reference of an other field from the model instance. I am trying to find the proper way of checking the referenced field value when the model is saving.

I thought i can use  contribute_to_class  function to place a signal like below:

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
            super(CropField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
            setattr(cls, name, CropFieldCreator(self))

            # Save tags back to the database post-save
            post_save.connect(self.post_save_function, cls)

        def post_save_function(self,  **kwargs):
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            try:
                instance.poster.file
            except:
                instance.cropping = '{}'
                instance.save()
```

This gives  error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison (runtime error ) i think while saving.

Do you think if this is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `instance.save()` in the except clause. This could be what's causing the infinite recursion.

Comment: Do you think it is the right place to put signal? Error is not about being in except because i have tried without except...

Comment: post_save_function() could be outside of the model class.
I also don't see the reason you need to override `contribute_to_class`. It would help if you could post the full model class definition or explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: http://paltman.com/2010/02/25/how-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-a-django-model/      a smilar thing...

Comment: Still think that the `save()` is causing it. Or would cause it if it was called. You should double check that you're not saving the object in anything called by `post_save`.